# USB 3.0 flash drive not working on USB 2.0 port

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive, flash

I've recently bought a USB 3.0 flash drive and wanted to try it out. I connected it to a 2.0 port and it didn't work. The light on it starts blinking for about 1 second and stops. I also get a message that a device was not recognised.

Earlier I managed to make it work after connecting and disconnecting it a few times. It worked fine until I disconnected it again.

I tried every port and it didn't work. I tried it on another computer (and even on a tablet) and it worked fine. I also searched for any info on the net, on the producers site and I didn't find anything helpful.

The port is ok. I tried a USB 2.0 flash drive and it worked fine.

Does anyone know what might the problem be?

Comment: Have you researched the issue here on SU before posting?

Comment: @AcePL I did but only thing that I found was a reverse problem - USB 2.0 devices not working on USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: You're sure? http://superuser.com/questions/874384/usb-3-0-hard-drive-in-usb-3-port-only-recognized-as-usb-2-and-detected-only-when

Comment: @AcePL It's a different problem. My flash drive isn't recognized at all.

Comment: Ok, let's try different approach. Have you tested the usb 3.0 on different port? If none available was it test on different machine? I know it's rather different issue, but you didn't do basic tests. Have you searched net for issues specific to this USB drive and/or machine with usb3.0? You wouldn't believe how often there are compatibility issues. It's not I (nor everybody else) don't want to help, but there's really nothing to work with. Edit your question to include above - ONLY THEN anything can be at least considered.

Comment: I did everything that you mentioned and thought it's a right place to ask this question. I updated the post with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possible issues.

1. you were sold a low-quality or fake (additional question: other machines - was it recognized as 3.0?). I see that you said it worked previously, but this is no indication of good drive
2. it doesn't slide into the port completely, thus not making full connection. I actually think it is the problem, since you say it works on other machines (BTW. you checked that yesterday, right?) and sort of works when you fiddle with it.
3. Disable selective suspend for USB in Power Management
4. Right click Computer --> Manage --> Devices. Can you see the Unidentified USB device there? Try update drivers. If unsuccessful, remove device and reinstall driver again.